# DNA replication precision

Tags: dna-replication

This will sound as a super stupid question, but I just read in the *Molecular biology of the gene* book (7th edition, Watson, Baker, Bell and al.) that **one mistake occurs in 10 million nucleotides added during the replication of DNA**.

However, I read in the Campbell's biology book (11th edition) that it is **one mistake in 10 billion nucleotides added**.

I tried to google it and kept finding these two numbers... probably because people use the same books as I do as sources. So, my question is the following: **which book is right about DNA replication precision?**

Thanks for your help and sorry if my question isn't very interesting.

Comment: Can you provide some longer passages from those books? I suspect one is reporting the number of errors before correction, and the other is reporting the number of errors after. That said, you should consider either number as a very rough approximation to within a couple orders of magnitude to interpret it generally.

Comment: Also, what organism are the books considering? Different organisms have different mutation rates. Trying to get something meaningful from these random numbers is useless.

Comment: The precision of DNA replication is determined by the fidelity of DNA polymerase, which depends, in part, on its proof-reading capacity. The ratio of correct:incorrect nucleotide insertions ranges from 10^3 (extremely low fidelity) to 10^10 (extremely high fidelity).